# Set std::boolalpha flag in header file?

Tags: c++, iostream

Is it possible to set `std::boolalpha` in a header file? My use case is for easy print debugging across my files when needed. I could place them in the same header with my overloads on `std::ostream& operator<<` instead of typing it out in `main()`.

Comment: If you want to print "debugging" across your program I recommend you look into one of the many logging frameworks available. While it will not solve your problem, it will help you with the task of logging, both debug and non-debug information.

Comment: As for `std::boolalpha` I suggest you read e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) and learn more about stream states.

Comment: You probably could if the use it in is a class or function template. But in general use an abstract base class to log and use dependency injection to inject an interface to your logging. Or better define a virtual base class with report methods and make an implementation that forwards to the logging system of the day (adapter) and inject that interface into your own code (the logging infrastructure should not be visible at all in your own code). This also will make unit testing much more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how to keep logging out of your production code and do formatting and selection of logging mechanism somewhere else.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Header file my_reporting_itf.h
struct my_reporting_itf
{
    // logging my never change the state of the object
    // and must not throw (logging infrastructure error should be handled and hidden)
    virtual void report_input_out_of_range(const std::string& value_name, int value) const noexcept = 0;
};

// Header file and C++ file std_cout_reporting_t.h and std_cout_reporting_t.cpp
// include my_reporting_itf.h
// in the cpp file you can use your 
struct std_cout_reporting_t final :
    public my_reporting_itf
{
    // forward to logging infrastructure of your choice
    void report_input_out_of_range(const std::string& value_name, int value) const noexcept override
    {
        // here is where you manage your logging formatting, and things like std::boolalpha
        // the setting could be a flag in std_cout_reporting_t's constructor
        std::cout << "Value : `" << value_name << "` is out of range, value = " << value << "\n";
    }
};

// Header file and C++ file null_reporting_t.h and null_reporting_t.cpp
// include my_reporting_itf.h
struct null_reporting_t :
    public my_reporting_itf
{
    // for unit testing do absolutely nothing
    void report_input_out_of_range(const std::string& value_name, int value) const noexcept override
    {
    }
};

// myclass.cpp and myclass.h
// A class with logging like this is unit testable
// in the header file for my_class_t you only have to include header file with my_reporting
// include my_reporting_itf.h (not dependend on any logging infrastructure
class my_class_t
{
public:
    explicit my_class_t(const my_reporting_itf& report) :
        m_report{ report }
    {
    };

    void set_value(int value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            m_report.report_input_out_of_range("value", value);
        }
    }

private:
    const my_reporting_itf& m_report;
};

// main.cpp
// here you include my_class_t.h, and std_cout_reporting_t.h
int main()
{
    std_cout_reporting_t report;
    // null_reporting_t report; for unit testing inject this (you can also inject a google_mock to test
    // if report functions are actually called when needed)
    
    my_class_t foo{ report };

    // out of range will result in a report
    foo.set_value(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

###### An example from the Standard Library

The problem with global objects, such as `std::cin` and `std::cout`, is just that. They're global. When somebody hands you one of them, and says, please do some stream I/O with this, you can never assume they have been configured in any particular way.

The same can be true for other stream objects, global or otherwise. You cannot always assume that a stream has the configuration you desire.

For that reason, it may be best to create some sort of RAII guard class that you can use to configure an I/O stream as you require. You can configure the stream in the ctor, and restore the previous configuration in the dtor.

As an example of this, consider the requirements imposed on *random number engines* and *random number distributions* in the C++ Standard Library. For those objects, `operator<<` and `operator>>` are required to configure their streams in a certain specific way, before they perform any I/O. On exit, the operators must restore the streams to their original configurations.

In order to comply with those requirements, I wrote the following RAII class.

```cpp
namespace tbx
{
    template <typename charT, typename traits>
    class configure_ostream_for_random_engine
    {
        // RAII "guard" class sets ostream fmtflags and fill character 
        // as required by section 26.6.2.4 of the C++ standard. 
        // Destructor restores original fmtflags and fill character.
        std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& ost_;
        std::ios_base::fmtflags const flags_;
        charT const fill_character_;
    public:
        configure_ostream_for_random_engine(
            std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& ost)
            : ost_{ ost }
            , flags_{ ost.flags(std::ios_base::dec | std::ios_base::left) }
            , fill_character_{ ost.fill(ost.widen(' ')) }
        {}
        ~configure_ostream_for_random_engine()
        {
            ost_.flags(flags_);
            ost_.fill(fill_character_);
        }
    private:
        configure_ostream_for_random_engine(
            configure_ostream_for_random_engine const&)
            = delete;
        configure_ostream_for_random_engine(
            configure_ostream_for_random_engine&&)
            = delete;
        configure_ostream_for_random_engine& operator= (
            configure_ostream_for_random_engine const&)
            = delete;
        configure_ostream_for_random_engine& operator= (
            configure_ostream_for_random_engine&&)
            = delete;
    };
}
```

There is a similar class for stream input: `tbx::configure_istream_for_random_engine`.

Writing a stream insertion `operator<<` starts out with a configuration object.

This example is from class `tbx::permuted_congruential_engine`, where `operator<<` is defined as a "hidden friend." That is why you see "friend" as part of the definition below.

```cpp
        template <typename charT, typename traits>
        friend auto operator<<
            ( std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& ost
            , permuted_congruential_engine const& e
            ) -> std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
        {
            tbx::configure_ostream_for_random_engine<charT, traits> 
                raii_guard(ost);
            // Output engine state
            //...
            // On exit, original stream configuration is automatically 
            // restored by the dtor of raii_guard.
        }
```

###### A general solution

You can do a similar thing with other streams.

In class `tbx::configure_ostream` below, the ctor establishes the default configuration used by output streams in the C++ Standard Library. Those are documented in function `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::init`. See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init).

It then goes one step further, by setting `boolalpha`.

```cpp
namespace tbx
{
    template< typename charT, typename traits >
    class configure_ostream
    {
        std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& ost_;
        std::streamsize const width_;
        std::streamsize const precision_;
        std::ios_base::fmtflags const flags_;
        charT const fill_character_;
    public:
        configure_ostream(std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& ost)
            : ost_{ ost }
            , width_{ ost.width(0) }
            , precision_{ ost.precision(6) }
            , flags_{ ost.flags(std::ios_base::dec | std::ios_base::skipws) }
            , fill_character_{ ost.fill(ost.widen(' ')) }
        {
            // The defaults established above are the same as those 
            // set by function std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::init.
            // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/init
            //
            // Additional settings follow:
            ost.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha);
        }
        ~configure_ostream()
        {
            ost_.width(width_);
            ost_.precision(precision_);
            ost_.flags(flags_);
            ost_.fill(fill_character_);
        }
    private:
        configure_ostream(configure_ostream const&)
            = delete;
        configure_ostream(configure_ostream&&)
            = delete;
        configure_ostream& operator= (configure_ostream const&)
            = delete;
        configure_ostream& operator= (configure_ostream&&)
            = delete;
    };
}
```

To demonstrate its use, I wrote struct `A`, which defines `operator<<` as a hidden friend.

```cpp
struct A
{
    int value{ 42 };
    bool flag{ true };
    friend auto operator<< (std::ostream& ost, A const& a) 
        -> std::ostream&
    {
        // This sets boolalpha, plus whatever other 
        // settings you put in class configure_ostream.

        tbx::configure_ostream raii_guard(ost);  // ***LOOK HERE***

        ost << "value : " << a.value 
            << "\nflag  : " << a.flag
            << "\n\n";
        return ost;
    }
};
```

Function `main` has a bunch of messed up settings for `std::cout`, but struct `A` ignores them.

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Set a bunch of random stream configurations.
    std::cout
        << std::noboolalpha
        << std::left
        << std::hex
        << std::setfill('*')
        << std::setw(20);

    // A{} ignores the random settings above, 
    // but "main" uses them.
    std::cout << A{} 
        << "main"
        << "\n42 decimal as hex : " << 42
        << "\nfalse             : " << false
        << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
value : 42
flag  : true

main****************
42 decimal as hex : 2a
false             : 0
```